# Sort list in C# with LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I want to sort a list in C#.

Like where structure property AVC goes to true then show them first then AVC goes to false. Are any way to do this in C# LINQ?

Answer (score 174, accepted):

Well, the simplest way using LINQ would be something like this:

```
list = list.OrderBy(x => x.AVC ? 0 : 1)
           .ToList();
```

or

```
list = list.OrderByDescending(x => x.AVC)
           .ToList();
```

I *believe* that the natural ordering of `bool` values is `false < true`, but the first form makes it clearer IMO, because everyone knows that `0 < 1`.

Note that this won't sort the original list itself - it will create a new list, and assign the reference back to the `list` variable. If you want to sort in place, you should use the [`List<T>.Sort`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3da4abas.aspx) method.

Comment: Is .ToList() necessary here?

Comment: @KrishnaPS: Yes, assuming the compile-time type of `list` is `List<T>`. Otherwise you'd be trying to assign an `IEnumerable<T>` to a `LIst<T>` variable. You don't need it if you just need a sequence which will be lazily evaluated every time you iterate over it though.

Comment: .Thank you! So order by returns a list which is lazily evaluated? Am I missing something here? Sorry that I am confused? I am facing a situation where I have ordered the list and returned it as IEnumerable as above, however when I do a for each on that returned list to change a value, I see that the order is disrupted..

Comment: @KrishnaPS: `OrderBy` returns a *sequence*, not a list. It sounds like you should be asking a new question demonstrating your problem though.

Comment: Kindly help me on this question that I have posted http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41738008/c-sharp-strange-behaviour-of-orderby-linq

Answer (score 19):

Like this?

In LINQ:

```
var sortedList = originalList.OrderBy(foo => !foo.AVC)
                             .ToList();
```

Or in-place:

```
originalList.Sort((foo1, foo2) => foo2.AVC.CompareTo(foo1.AVC));
```

As Jon Skeet says, the trick here is knowing that `false` is considered to be 'smaller' than `true.`

If you find that you are doing these ordering operations in lots of different places in your code, you might want to get your type `Foo` to implement the `IComparable<Foo>` and `IComparable` interfaces.

Answer (score 16):

I assume that you want them sorted by something else also, to get a consistent ordering between all items where AVC is the same. For example by name:

```
var sortedList = list.OrderBy(x => c.AVC).ThenBy(x => x.Name).ToList();
```

Answer (score 2):

A syntax alternative for the accepted answer:

```cs
list = from item in list
       orderby item.AVC
       select item;
```

Keep in mind that "list" is now an [IEnumerable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.ienumerable-1?view=net-5.0) object and not a [List](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1?view=net-5.0) one.