# For Each Item Control Loop is Random... Need it Sequential as in GroupBox

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to loop through multiple text box controls inside a group box. The code writes the text box values to a temp file in reverse order.

I have the following code:

- Should be S1, S2, S3, .... S10
- Writes as S10, S9, S8,.... S1

What's wrong?

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    file = My.Computer.FileSystem.OpenTextFileWriter("c:\Temp.txt", False)

    For Each item As Control In sourceGroupBox.Controls
        If TypeOf item Is TextBox Then
            If Len(item.Text) > 0 Then
                file.WriteLine(item.Text)
            End If
        End If
    Next

    file.Close()

End Sub
```

Comment: Have you tried an `OrderBy` function? It's in the `System.Linq` namespace, it's an extension method on objects that implement `IEnumerable`. (ControlCollection implements it).

Comment: You could [sort it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4003835/sort-list-in-c-sharp-with-linq)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You could do it with a for loop of the ids.

```
For id As Integer = 1 To 10
    Dim item As TextBox = CType(sourceGroupBox.Controls("S" & id), TextBox)

    If Len(item.Text) > 0 Then
        file.WriteLine(item.Text)
    End If
Next
```

Answer (score 2):

The Controls collection isn't necessarily in any particular order.  You can, however, leverage LINQ to get them in the order you want:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    file = My.Computer.FileSystem.OpenTextFileWriter("c:\Temp.txt", False)

    For Each item As Control In sourceGroupBox.Controls.OfType(Of TextBox).OrderBy(Function(x) x.Name)
        If Len(item.Text) > 0 Then
            file.WriteLine(item.Text)
        End If
    Next

    file.Close()

End Sub
```

This assumes that you've been giving the textboxes the names using 2 digits for the number

Comment: What version of VS are you using?  If I'm not mistaken some of the older versions you need to `Imports System.Linq`

Comment: Although this would order them as "S1", "S10", "S2", "S3", etc. A better ordering would be to check for and strip the "S", then order by parsing the rest of the name as an integer.

Comment: Number them using 2 digits and they'll come out in order, "S01", "S02"