# Sorting Generic List in C#

Tags: c#-3.0, asp.net-3.5

I have a generic List as shown in below.

```
List<UsrProfile> lst = GetUsers();
lst.Sort();
ddlUser1.DataSource = lst;
ddlUser1.DataBind();
```

Now the dropdown has both Value and Text. Now I do I sort by Text using the Generic list.

Please help. 
I cannot use LinQ

Comment: You can't use Linq because you don't know how, or because this is a homework assignment?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sort list in C# with LINQ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4003835/sort-list-in-c-sharp-with-linq)

Comment: @Adrian I'm guessing "I cannot use LinQ" means that they are not allowed to because of some constraints. So that link wouldn't work for them.

Comment: Agreed. I Missed "I cannot use LinQ".

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly (and I may not...it's not very clear), you want to sort the list by a specific member of the `UsrProfile` class. Specifically, the `Text` property.

This is easy to do: `lst.Sort((u1, u2) => u1.Text.CompareTo(u2.Text));` should do what you want.

This passes a `Comparison<UsrProfile>` delegate instance to the `List<UsrProfile>.Sort()` method, allowing it to customize the comparison logic used for the sort. In this case, rather than comparing whole `UsrProfile` objects against each other, it just compares the `Text` property between objects.