# Ordering List<string> that contains keywords from a template c#

Tags: c#, string, list

I have a problem. I need to order a C# `List<string>` based on a template, but the template contains only a part of the string, so it must be `Contains()`.
The template would be something like:

```
House
Vehicle
Electric
```

and the input something like:

```
Electric bike
Household appliances
Electricity
Electric generator
Vehicle appliances
```

and the ordered list should be like:

```
Household appliances
Vehicle appliances
Electric bike
Electricity
Electric generator
```

Is there anything that can help me?

Comment: you could write a custom comparer see this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4003849/1037841 and or this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3007470/custom-sort-logic-in-orderby-using-linq#3008387 The comparer would check, if both elements contain a keyword and then decides whichever comes first. Q:In your scenario what if the string is Vehicle House Electric (contains all of your template stuff)?

Comment: thanks for your reply, I will check those questions, for your scenario it would be listed under Vehicle since it starts with

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must implement custom comparer

```
public class CustomStringComparer : IComparer<string>
{
    List<string> templates = new List<string> { "House", "Vehicle", "Electric" };
    public int Compare(string x, string y)
    {
        string xTemplate = templates.FirstOrDefault(t => x.Contains(t));
        string yTemplate = templates.FirstOrDefault(t => y.Contains(t));
        int xTemplateIndex = templates.IndexOf(xTemplate);
        int yTemplateIndex = templates.IndexOf(yTemplate);
        return xTemplateIndex.CompareTo(yTemplateIndex);
    }
}
```

And then you can pass this comparer to Sort()

```
List<string> input = new List<string>
{
    "Electric bike",
    "Household appliances",
    "Electricity",
    "Electric generator",
    "Vehicle appliances"
};

input.Sort(new CustomStringComparer());
```