# C# - Sort items of linked list by date

Tags: c#, sorting, datetime, linked-list

I am having a Node

```
public class Node
{
    public Node(Pupil pupil)
    {
        Data = pupil;
        Next = null;
    }
    public Pupil Data { get; set; }
    public Node Next { get; set; }
}
```

which holds the date of birth of a student. I insert objects to the list like this

```
public void Insert(Pupil pupil)
{
    if (_head == null)
    {
        _head = new Node(pupil);
        return;
    }

    Node current = _head;

    while (current.Next != null)
    {
        current = current.Next;
    }

    current.Next = new Node(pupil);
}
```

But now i have the problem to sort the pupils by date of birth (pupil.DateOfBirth). Since I am new to Lists etc. I dont have an idea how to do this. Since corona is here we have to basically teach it ourselves in university.
Help would be really appreciated.

Comment: Probably here u can find solution:
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4003835/sort-list-in-c-sharp-with-linq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4003835/sort-list-in-c-sharp-with-linq)
There is dedicated library for operations on Lists and Collections very similar to those in SQL and it's called LINQ, check it out in spare time that will help you at university

Comment: @Hesh: If the OP really has to implement linked lists, then LINQ will not help much.

Comment: @Xaver Oh, I didn't noticed that was linked list. Anyway he could check out LINQ for future problems.

Comment: Yes, definitely. LINQ is a really nice and helpful tool.

Comment: Sadly I need to do it manually

Comment: Why does the pandemic affect your instructor's teaching?  Surely you all have access to Zoom?  Do you really require the instructor's physical presence to learn from them?

Comment: The thing is our teachers don't use zoom. We have to learn it ourselves.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose you have an object called `unorderedList` (containing your pupils in an unordered fashion) and an object called `orderedList`, which initially is empty. Then you can do the following:

1. Take an element of `unorderedList`. It is not important which element you take. For example, you can always take the first one (which is also a good idea if the list is already partially ordered). Let's call this element `temp`.
2. Add `temp` to the correct position of `orderedList`.
3. Remove `temp` from `unorderedList`.
4. Do steps 1-3 until `unorderedList` is empty.

This algorithm is called *insertion sort*. The [Wikipedia article on insertion sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insertion_sort) also contains an implementation in C. You could take a look at it to get an idea how you could do it in C#.

*Insertion sort* is a rather primitive sorting approach. Other approaches (such as quicksort, mergesort, etc.) may be faster, but are also harder to implement.

Comment: can you show me an example I dont know how to code this

Comment: I updated my answer. The Wikipedia article I liked contains an exemplary implementation.